# JDBC import module not found

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following imports..

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
```

But they come up with the error

```
is declared but module does not read it
```

I assume its because its not imported?  But I thought NetBeans just came with this?
Also, when I follow tutorials online how to import it, they all show right clicking on the project and "PROPERTIES" which you the select Libraries.  However, my version of NetBeans doesn't have libraries as an option to choose here.

I figure its in the "Dependencies" Sections, but when I click Add Dependency, I don't know what to search for.  I search JDBC, and SQL, and all this stuff comes up but I don't know which package to choose.

How do I import the JDBC drivers?

Comment: Which java version are you using ?

Comment: Im using 15.0.1

Comment: Do you use maven or gradle?

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` in the sources root of your project? What does it contain? As an aside the `java.sql` package is not a JDBC driver, it is the JDBC API, which is included in Java, but if you have a modular project and are not explicitly requiring the right module(s), it won't be available to you.

Comment: Yeah, I just deleted module-info.java and it worked. It also made a bunch of my other API's I had trouble importing.  So yay!

Comment: Deleting `module-info.java` is one option. The other is to list the modules you need.